# Perform additional aggregation on an existing Mongoose aggregate result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I want to take the result of a Mongoose `Model.aggregate` command and perform additional aggregation methods on it. The idea is that I can query the database just once, aggregate to a certain point, then perform additional aggregation methods on those results without having to requery the database again. (Code below is Coffeescript)

```
firstAggregation = [
    {
      $geoNear: {
        near:
          type: "Point"
          coordinates: geo
        includeLocs: "geo"
        distanceField: "distance"
        maxDistance: distance
        spherical: true
        uniqueDocs: true
      }
    },
    {
      $match: { "active" : true }
    }
  ]

secondAggregation = firstAggregation.concat [
        {
          $unwind: "$offers"
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$offers"
          }
        }
      ]

app.MyModel.aggregate firstAggregation, (err, results) ->

  # ... do something with the first results ...

  # **** apply secondAggregation here! ****
  # the below doesn't work, but its what I want to achieve

  results.aggregate secondAggregation, (err, secondResults) ->
    # ... do something with the second results without having requeried the DB ...
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't pass in the results from one aggregation to a second aggregation. While you could pass a list of document `_id`s to filter on using `$in`, beyond that, there's really not much else you could do.

```
{ $match : { _id : { $in: [ /* list of _ids */] } } }
```

- `$match` [reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)
- `$in` [reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

Although given current v2.4 limitations of the aggregation framework results (capped at a 16MB result), you could perform similar logic to what you might want to have done on the database in memory on the client (in this case NodeJS).

In the example above in your question, it looks like it's just for example trying to find all of the distinct values for an array of values for the field `offers`?

```
offerNames = {}
for result in results
    for offer in result.offers
        offerNames[i] = (offerNames[i] or 0) + 1

for name, value of offerNames
    console.log name + " = " + value
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! Yes, my example above is pretty basic, so I'll have a go at some manual manipulation of the data, but I was hoping it would be possible to keep using the clean syntax of the aggregation pipeline for some trickier issues.